# Using python CSV or openpyxl compare two excel/csv sheet data and replace one of the files with other file values

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl

I am new to python and CSV and openpyxl modules. I have below requirement.I have two excel/csv files File1 and File2. I have to loop through File1 first two rows (row1, row2)of cells and compare with the File2 first two rows((row1, row2)) of cells and whenever two cells in both files match, i need to pickup the row3 cell value and row4 cell value of File1 and update it to row3 cell value and row4 cell value in File2. the end goal is to iterate through file1 and compare with file 2 and update the values in file2. I will be okay with using one more file as long as it has File2 values after updating. I will be really glad if someone can look into it and guide me. So far I have used CSV but it has some limitations and not able to achieve the end result. 
The limitation i have is that, in the new file generated i am able to populate only matched record but not all  File2 values after updating. i am open to openpyxl or xlrd, xlwt aswell.

```
 with open('newfile.csv', 'w+') as newFile:
            writer = csv.writer(newFile, delimiter = ',')
            with open('File1.csv', 'r') as r:
                with open('File2.csv', 'r') as p:
                    reader = csv.reader(r)
                    portreader = csv.reader(p)
                    first = []
                    second = []
                    for row in reader:
                        first.append(row)
                    for portRow in portreader:
                        second.append(portRow)
                        #dummy2 = firstlist
                    for slist in second:
                        #i =0
                        for firstlist in first:
                            if(slist[0] == firstlist[0] and slist[1] == firstlist[1]):
          writer.writerow(firstlist)
```

[File1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAbVu.png)

[File2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O64gH.png)

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of the comparison logic? And also clarify the CSV/XLSX stuff. With XLSX you don't need to worry about creating a new file.

Comment: I need to fill the cells of row3 and row4 of File2. Ex: Both File 1 and File 2 has A-4, 41 in their row 1 and row 2 cells respectively (slist[0] == firstlist[0] and slist[1] == firstlist[1]), this where the condition matches, then I need to pick up the respective row3 and row4 cell values from File1 and insert them in respective File2  row3 and row4 cell values, i.e 1, 890 should be inserted from File1 to File2 not affecting the other cell values of same row and other rows, this loop runs and insert values in File2 row3 and row4 cells. openpyxl or CSV with just values fill up in File2 is fine.